# Additional filtering options for Sharepoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to know if it's possible to filter single-line-text columns in a list, the same way as People columns? What I mean is that in a People column, you can type what you want to filter it by, but for single-line-text columns, I just get an infinite list of all items, with no way to filter them. (See picture)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid we cannot achieve your requirement in the modern view in SharePoint online.

We cannot type the key words to filter the text when using filter by in the modern view in SharePoint online.

It is by design.

Comment: Not surprised to be honest... What a pain it is to work with Sharepoint. Thank you.